# Several levels of footnotes with different font size.

Tags: footnotes, fontsize, manyfoot

I am trying to create a document with two different levels of footnotes using the manyfoot package. I'd like the second level of footnotes to have a smaller fontsize than the first (say, footnotesize for the first and scriptsize for the second). How can I achieve this?

Here is my minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{perpage}
\usepackage[perpage]{manyfoot}

\DeclareNewFootnote{A}[alph]

\begin{document}

Some random text\footnote{First level of footnotes.} here\footnoteA{Second level of footnotes, which I would like to have a smaller font size.}. 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for `manyfoot` introduces hooks with `\SetFootnoteHook{}` which should be issued before `\DeclareNewFootnote`.

Note that you can always locate the documentation using the command-line/terminal by writing `texdoc manyfoot`, and that works for any package. The documentation is also available at http://ctan.org/pkg/manyfoot

It might sound tedious to look up the documentation for various small problems/features, but the package documentations tend to be well-written and easy to browse. Also, it will at the same time help you to understand how LaTeX works.

**Output**

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{perpage}
\usepackage[perpage]{manyfoot}

\SetFootnoteHook{\scriptsize}
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}[alph]

\begin{document}

Some random text\footnote{First level of footnotes.} here\footnoteA{Second level of footnotes, in a smaller font size.}. 

\end{document}
```